# Date type field is taking default value in ruby rails , how to validate the date format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Date type field in my database, I want to validate the format of date, the issue i am facing is that even if i am entering invalid format like "11/ /" (string format) it is taking some default date(ex 1970-01-01) while saving, so  I am not able to validate it, since the default value format is always correct. How to handle this, so that can add error if format is invalid? I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails,

```
field :date_of_birth, type: Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex validation for a string like `'1985/01/01'`

```
validates_format_of :date_of_birth, with: /\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use validates_timeliness gem https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness, it's very simple!